# Is there a way to control bass and treble under Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, audio

My volume control device for my speakers recently decided to stop working so now I am forced to control the volume through purely software means, but my sub-woofer is still a little too loud.

Is there anyway to control the bass and treble under Windows 7? I remember this being a feature under XP but I've looked all over the mixer options and I don't see anything.

Is Windows itself doesn't have this feature, can someone recommend a good third party application?

Comment: Do you have the subwoofer connected separately, or a plain splitter?

Comment: Plain splitter I think. Cable runs from the soundcard to the sub, which connects to the two satellites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up redownloading the driver package for my card, as I previously installed just the driver. Once I installed the driver and the software, I could mix down the bass in the equalizer that is part of the software suite for the soundcard.

Answer (score 17):

The following directions only work if you have the drivers for your soundcard that support this feature.

1. Click on the volume control icon near the clock on the taskbar.
2. Click on your audio output device's icon (probably will be a speaker icon)
3. In the window that opens, select the Enhancements tab.
4. Check the box for "immediate mode" then click apply if you want to test your settings as you change them.
5. Look for an option in the list labeled, "Equalizer" or similar.  Check that, then adjust the settings in the bottom half of the window (see the picture below).

[image: Screenshot of the Enhancements tab of the properties for my speakers]

As you can see in this screenshot from my computer, this is a function provided by my sound card's drivers (my sound card was made by Realtek), so if you do not see this option, you might be using just basic drivers that come with Windows.  If this is the case, look for a Windows 7 driver for your sound card from your computer manufacturer or sound card manufacturer.

Comment: Unfortunately my card does not support this.

Comment: But +1 for telling me that icon actually does something

Comment: What sound card do you have?

Comment: HTO Striker 7.1

Comment: wow I came back to my computer with this up and sat here like a fool clicking the x button and then ok.

Comment: -1 This is specific to sound card drivers.

Answer (score 1):

- Open Volume Mixer on your Taskbar.
- Click on the picture of the speakers, click the Enhacements tab, and select Bass Booster.
- If you want to increase it more, click on settings on the same tab and select the dB Boost Level.

Answer (score 0):

[RealTime Equalizer](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Multimedia/Audio/Audio-Plugins/RealTime-Equalizer.shtml):

> RTEQ 4 was designed to be an useful utility for processing music files
>   like MP3s or WAVs and for real time adjustment of audio signals from
>   sound card inputs.
>
> Its main purpose is to process the music to suit the users taste. The
>   equalizer achieves this demand by processing the frequency spectrum of
>   the music.
>
> It comes with two versions: a Winamp Plugin and a stand-alone version,
>   which can be used with other players like iTunes or Real Player.

Comment: I tried this but couldn't figure out how to get it to process the sound from programs as opposed to my microphone. It was kind of fun and trippy once I realized I was just listening to myself :). But seriously, how do you select the input? I think maybe the instructions need to be updated for Windows 7 and later... it says "Select an input and output from your sound card. This can be accomplished with the Volume Control located in Start/Programs/Accessories/Entertainment" but this doesn't exist, at least not for me.

Answer (score 0):

i just click on the sound in the task bar,it shows the volume and below that i click on mixer when the mixer opens up it gives me two options because i uninstalled win meda player,anyway "literally" click on the speaker icon the picture of the little speaker understand than your Speaker properites will open,then follow Gareth instructions,but you should be able to figure it out now,i use windows 7 an soundcards i dont think has anything do do with it,its windows app works on anything,works for me!

Answer (score 0):

If you install the proper driver package from the vendor (e.g. motherboard manufacturer would distribute on-board audio device drivers), then the available settings will be substantially increased, which you'll see in the device's properties (which you can get to via system tray the volume controller). Most all offer the ability to set the treble/bass *after* you have installed the right driver/app suite. There are only a few manufacturers of PC audio cards.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use 3rd party software equalizer. It's driver-independend.

I use **Equalizer APO** - A system-wide equalizer for Windows 7 / 8 / 8.1 / 10 and it works perfectly. It's free, [downloadable from sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/equalizerapo/)